# Quick question on purpose of adjunct

Tags: adverbs

What does the adverb 'primarily' modify in the below sentence?

> The purpose of the new policy is primarily to attract investment from abroad.

To me, it seems that 'primarily' modifies the infinitival clause *to attract investment from abroad*. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that's right. However, had the author written the primary purpose, we'd end up with the same meaning.

Comment: Yes, here "primarily" is called a 'partial restrictive focusing modifier. The 'focus' is the infinitival clause "to attract investment from abroad".

Comment: @BillJ. What is a 'partial restrictive focusing modifier'?

Comment: The restriction may be partial, compared to absolute: compare "The purpose of the new policy is **primarily** to attract investment from abroad" (partial) ~ "The purpose of the new policy is **only** to attract investment from abroad" (restrictive)